# Type error: Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

**services.yml** located in src/EliteFifa/MatchBundle/Resources/services.yml

```
parameters:
    # repositories
    match_repository.class:             EliteFifa\MatchBundle\Repository\MatchRepository
    match_repository.factory_argument:  'MatchBundle:Match'

# services
match_service.class:                EliteFifa\MatchBundle\Service\MatchService

services:
    # services
    elite_fifa.match_service:
        class: %match_service.class%
        arguments:
          - '@elite_fifa.match_repository'
          - '@=service("form.factory")'
          - '@elite_fifa.standing_service'
```

.

```
class MatchService
{
    /**
     * @var MatchRepository
     */
    private $matchRepository;

    /**
     * @var FormFactory
     */
    private $formFactory;

    /**
     * @var StandingService
     */
    private $standingService;

    /**
     * @param MatchRepository $matchRepository
     * @param FormFactory $formFactory
     * @parma StandingService $standingService
     */
    public function __construct(
        MatchRepository $matchRepository,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        StandingService $standingService)
    {
        $this->matchRepository = $matchRepository;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->standingService = $standingService;
    }
```

All of a sudden Symfony has stopped recognizing additional arguments, I've added `- '@elite_fifa.standing_servicee'` but get the following error:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   EliteFifa\MatchBundle\Service\Mat     chService::__construct(), 2
>   passed in /home/owner/Desktop/Workspace/EFL/var
>   /cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1128 and exactly 3
>   expected

I've tried clearing the cache but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What are you trying to do with @=service(form.factory)?  Seems unnecessary.

Comment: Did you ever solve this as having the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `'@=service("form.factory")'` by `'@form.factory'`

```
parameters:
    # repositories
    match_repository.class:             EliteFifa\MatchBundle\Repository\MatchRepository
    match_repository.factory_argument:  'MatchBundle:Match'

# services
match_service.class:                EliteFifa\MatchBundle\Service\MatchService

services:
    # services
    elite_fifa.match_service:
        class: %match_service.class%
        arguments:
          - '@elite_fifa.match_repository'
          - '@form.factory'
          - '@elite_fifa.standing_service'
```